# Clone and then mutate approach in redux

Tags: redux, clone, immutability, ngrx

I've been reading stuff on redux for a while. And there is a strange thing for me. In most examples people give, all the copying logic is handled via reducers.
I'm using typescript and want to adopt a more class-based approach. But maybe I'm missing something.

Let's say I have a shopping Cart class. Along with cart reducer and cart actions.
It looks the following way:

```js
export class Cart
{
    private items:{[key:string]:number} = {};

    constructor(items:{[key:string]:number} = {})
    {
        Object.assign(this.items, items);
    }

    public addItem(id:string)
    {
        this.items[id] = this.items[id]?this.items[id]+1:1;
    }

    public removeItem(id:string)
    {
        this.items[id]--;

        if(this.items[id] <= 0)
        {
            delete this.items[id];
        }

    }

    public setItemsCount(id:string, count:number)
    {
        this.items[id] = count;
    }

    public clone():Cart
    {
        return new Cart(Object.assign({}, this.items));
    }

}
```

So, here I'm incapsulating cloning logic in a class.

And in my reducer I would go with the signature:

```
function reducer(state = new Cart(), action:Action): Cart {
    //first clone, then mutate, then return
}
```

Or, actually, how about simply deep-cloning objects via a universal method, then mutating them and then returning? What's bad about that approach?

Comment: Why not add a method to the `Cart` class that takes an update from your action and returns a new instance of `Cart` based on it's existing values and the update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is considered bad practice for several reasons.

First, keeping class instances in state is discouraged [because it will break time-travel debugging](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#organizing-state-non-serializable).  You *can* do it, but it's not the "right" way.

Second, your class is directly mutating its contents.  This will also break time-travel debugging, and [result in your connected React components not re-rendering properly](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html#react-not-rerendering).

Third, Redux encourages a more functional approach, not OOP.

You may want to read through my two recent blog posts, [The Tao of Redux, Part 1 - Implementation and Intent](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/05/idiomatic-redux-tao-of-redux-part-1/) and [The Tao of Redux, Part 2 - Practice and Philosophy](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/05/idiomatic-redux-tao-of-redux-part-2/), which go into detail on what technical limitations Redux requires and why, why common practices exist for using Redux, and why other approaches may be *possible* but are not considered idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

You might go this way. After all ... You'll respect the immutability contract needed by Redux architecture.

**But I wouldn't recommend you to do that.**

Deep cloning is not performant at all. The bigger is your store, the slower will be your app.

Plus, to be honnest I tried this approach with a `class` : 
https://github.com/maxime1992/pizza-sync/blob/5212a29ee9be916383f759a3a129f7b580ed32ea/frontend/src/app/shared/state/orders/orders.reducer.ts

And it's not so bad. But I ended up using a simple function.

One thing tho, your `actions` here won't be typed so you will loose some benefits of Typescript.

Instead of doing that, you should create a `class` per action, as explained in this talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cyaAhXHhxgk

Also, I've made an ngrx starter that might help you get started : https://github.com/maxime1992/angular-ngrx-starter

Comment: According to @markerikson comment, just one thing to clarify : I didn't used a class as a direct reducer and all my methods were static so time travelling wasn't broke in my case which is slightly different than yours