# Changing class properties with Object.assign but returning class instance

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutability

I have a very basic `Person` class which requires a parameter called `data`.

```
class Person implements PersonInterface {

   constructor(public data) {

   }

   get name(): string {
      return this.data.name;
   }

}

const person: PersonInterface = new Person({ name: "Aristona });
```

In my Redux store, I keep all the persons in an array. It looks like this:

```
[Person, Person, Person, Person]
```

User can edit the name property of a `Person`. So my reducer looks like this:

```
case Constants.PERSON_UPDATE_SUCCESS:
  const person = Object.assign({}, action.payload.person.data, {
     name: action.payload.name
  });

  return {
    ...state,
    persons: [
      person,
      ...state.persons.filter(p => p.id !== person.id)
    ]
  };
```

It does not work because `Object.assign` returns the `data` property. What I need is `Person` object with `data` property updated. If I could mutate the data, it would look like this:

```
person.name = action.payload.name;
```

Otherwise, my persons array look like this:

```
[Person, Person, Person, Person, Object] // Object is data
```

and it breaks all the iterations.

I tried doing this:

```
const updatedData = Object.assign({}, action.payload.person.data, {
   name: action.payload.name
});

const person: PersonInterface = new Person(updatedData);
```

While in theory it would work, sadly I cannot instantiate a class like this without making major changes on my `PersonFactory` classes.

Is there any way to achieve this without breaking immutability of Redux?

Thank you.

Comment: If you really want to use classes, I recommend to just create a new instance of the class using `new`.

Comment: React and especially redux take a more functional approach rather than object oriented. I can't think of a good way to do what you're trying to do, unfortunately. I must ask, do you really need to use classes for your state? The state is just a data structure and wouldn't really benefit from being a class instance.

Comment: See my answer on why use of classes for data in Redux is discouraged: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44268317/clone-and-then-mutate-approach-in-redux/44270061#44270061 .

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with Faris that storing class instances in Redux is not a good practice, how about

```
const person = Object.assign(new Person(), ...);
```

where `...` is the updated data.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is not a good practice to store class instances in your state

The first principle of redux's three principles says

> The state of your whole application is stored in an object tree within a single store. This makes it easy to create universal apps, as the state from your server can be serialized and hydrated into the client with no extra coding effort...

so consider changing your state to have only serializable data.

2. It is a good practice to use tools like [immutablejs](https://web.archive.org/web/20190206023710/https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/), it will take all immutability issues away and forever.
3. It is a good practice to split your reducer functions, consider using [combineReducer][2], if you do, you will have a reducer responsible only for the `persons` branch of the state.
4. If you must go on with the current solution, i think you have to instantiate a `new` Person on every update.

[2]: http://1)%20It%20is%20not%20a%20good%20practice%20to%20store%20class%20instances%20in%20your%20state%20%20The%20first%20principle%20of%20redux's%20three%20principles%20says%20%20%20%3E%20The%20state%20of%20your%20whole%20application%20is%20stored%20in%20an%20object%20tree%20within%20a%20single%20store.%20This%20makes%20it%20easy%20to%20create%20universal%20apps,%20as%20the%20state%20from%20your%20server%20can%20be%20serialized%20and%20hydrated%20into%20the%20client%20with%20no%20extra%20coding%20effort...%20%20so%20consider%20changing%20your%20state%20to%20have%20only%20serializable%20data.%20%202)%20It%20is%20a%20good%20practice%20to%20use%20tools%20like%20[immutablejs](https://web.archive.org/web/20190206023710/https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/),%20it%20will%20take%20all%20immutability%20issues%20away%20and%20forever.%20%203)%20It%20is%20a%20good%20practice%20to%20use%20split%20your%20reducer%20functions,%20consier%20using%20%20%20%20%20[%5C[1%5C]:%20https://fa](https://web.archive.org/web/20190206023710/https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/)cebook.github.io/immutable-js/%20%20%20%20%20[1](https://web.archive.org/web/20190206023710/https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/):%20http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html

Comment: I don't agree with 1. It's completely normal to save instances of classes to store. It's more about the complexity of the given object than about the fact that it's a class. For example we all save `Date` and `Error` instances to store.

Comment: it works, but it is not scalable as again it is not serializable, what happens if you want to persist your state in localStorage, or if you have server side rendering and you want to transfer state from server to client?

Comment: @Sulthan: no, it's not "normal" to save instances of classes into the store - it's heavily discouraged.  You _can_ do it, but ideally you should _only_ put plain data in the store - objects, arrays, and primitives.  Things like dates and errors should be represented by strings or numbers.

Comment: @markerikson An error or a date are the simplest of objects and redux has absolutely no problem handling them. Redux does not care what's inside if it's not mutated.

Comment: You may want to read my blog post [The Tao of Redux, Part 1 - Implementation and Intent](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/05/idiomatic-redux-tao-of-redux-part-1/), which discusses what actual limitations Redux requires and why those limitations exist.  As a summary: yes, you absolutely _can_ put anything you want in Redux, but non-serializable values will generally break time-travel debugging and persistence use cases.  Also see the related Redux FAQ at http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#organizing-state-non-serializable .  (Source: I'm a Redux maintainer.)

Comment: If your architecture doesn't even allow me to use ES6 classes and all the goodies come along with (Typescript, type safety, interfaces, object composition, dependency injection and DI containers, value objects etc.) maybe your idea of using functional programming just doesn't work well? I just can't leave all the good programming habits on the side just to put some dumb object literals into Redux store. I'm not saying OOP is better than functional, usually they go hand in hand in my projects, but relying on simple object literals is so outdated.

Comment: @markerikson Do you think it would be possible for Redux or React to allow non-serializable data in the store but still keep the time-travel? Do you think it would be possible with the current implementation of JS? Maybe there could be some extensions/patterns that may improve the reducers and handle serialization issues for classes.

Comment: @Aristona: Uh... as a general observation, "functional programming" is primarily about simple functions operating on simple data structures, and _not_ using classes or OOP.  You're welcome to write your own code however you want, I'm just telling you what the idiomatic approach is for using Redux, and what issues you're likely to run into.  For what it's worth, there are many people using Redux and TypeScript together - see some of the articles in the [Static Typing](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/static-typing.md) section of my React/Redux links list.